# Get all data from two tables and group it into different category in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

These are my tables to build an FAQ:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_section` (
    `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `section_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`section_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `section_id_UNIQUE` (`section_id`),
    KEY `section_id_idx` (`section_title`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `tbl_topic` (
    `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `topic_title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `topic_id_UNIQUE` (`topic_id`),
    KEY `section_id_idx` (`section_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `section_id` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_section` (`section_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `tbl_faq` (
    `faq_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `faq_title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    `faq_description` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
    `faq_views` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`faq_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `faq_id_UNIQUE` (`faq_id`),
    KEY `topic_id_idx` (`topic_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `topic_id` FOREIGN KEY (`topic_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_topic` (`topic_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=127 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I have some how come up with a query:

```
SELECT a.topic_id as tid, a.topic_title as topic, 
    (SELECT b.faq_title FROM tbl_faq AS b WHERE b.topic_id = a.topic_id LIMIT 1) as question,
    (SELECT b.faq_description FROM tbl_faq AS b WHERE b.topic_id = a.topic_id LIMIT 1) as answer 
    FROM tbl_topic AS a
    WHERE a.section_id = 1;
```

When executed it works but gives only the first row of each TOPIC (I deliberately put that LIMIT 1 just to see if code is working)

Actually I need all question-answers with their respective **TOPIC** in rows which should look like :

**TOPIC HEADER ONE**

Question One
Answer One

Question Two
Answer Two

**TOPIC HEADER TWO**

Question Three
Answer Three

Question Four
Answer Four
and on...

Hope I have clarified my stand.

Comment: Hi - and welcome to the forums. When asking a question, could you please provide DDL (CREATE TABLE blah (....)) and also the DML (INSERT INTO blah VALUES(...))? This makes like much easier for those of us trying to help you. Take the tour and check out the "help us to help you" blog (both at the bottom left of the page).

Comment: I have created the table and the table structure is shown above. All I need is a piece of query to get the data. I am totally confused about it. Just a starter in db.

Comment: Run the command SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_topic\G (&c.). And then **you** go to the trouble of typing out the commands necessary to input the data - INSERT INTO tbl_topic VALUES(1, 'Topic Hear One'); &c. **Otherwise** that means that those who wish to help have to do it. You will find that you will get **far** more help if you do those simple things, rather than expect others to do it for you. That way, those who wish to help just have to copy and paste your DDL/DML into their servers - run a query or two, and then provide you with an answer. **Help us to help you**.

Comment: Please refer for the edited details.

Comment: You probably need a simple join: `SELECT t.topic_id AS tid, t.topic_title AS topic, f.faq_title, f.faq_description FROM tbl_topic AS t JOIN tbl_faq AS f ON f.topic_id = t.topic_id WHERE t.section_id = 1;`

Comment: Hey @JerryJones, can you provide us some `INSERTs` statements and you expected output editing your question? Should be helpful for us, so we can help you faster.